# Does pandas consume more resources like memory?

Tags: python, pandas

I have .csv file with only 2 columns. ("left" and "right")
The file size is less than 200 MB
I use the following code on **dev server** and it works as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('en_bigram.csv')
st = df[df["right"] == "some_text"]["left"]
st[st.str.startswith("My")].to_list()
```

"pandas" module is not installed on **production server**. I will like to know if

*I should install pandas*

or

*I should rewrite the code in pure python*

Is there any overhead (like memory/ cpu) in using pandas in production?
Can the 4 lines pandas code written using python's built in modules like csv in 4 or 5 lines?

Comment: I think you should clarify. What function do you exactly need? Loading the `pandas` library will definitely take more memory than loading the `csv` library, but being able to write the same functionalities with the same number of lines is restricted by what you're actually doing.

Comment: I need to extract all strings into a list from "left" column starting with "My" where "right" column is "some_text".

Comment: Yes, this could be done with relatively simple code, although longer than 4 lines if you want to write it clearly. `pandas` can definitely require more memory than processing a cvs file line-by-line, which you could do here. If your final result is a `list`, then I see no good reason to use `pandas` for something as simple as this, but this question is too opinion-based, IMO. Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/de0b3ba1ed641b0c3f926217222b53bd

Comment: If in case a lot users visit the site, will it scale to open the 200 MB file every time as you have suggested?

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following experiments on my machine (Intel 9th Gen i7) with a test data file of ~535 MB:

#### Pandas version

```py
# import measurement dependencies

import time
import psutil


p = psutil.Process()
start = time.process_time()

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
st = df[df["right"] == "some_text"]["left"]
res = st[st.str.startswith("My")].to_list()

print(time.process_time() - start)
print(p.memory_percent())
```

#### Pure Python Version

```py
# import measurement dependencies

import time
import psutil

p = psutil.Process()
start = time.process_time()

import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(r, None)
    left = headers.index("left")
    right = headers.index("right")

    res = [line for line in r if line[right] == "some_text" and line[left].startswith('My')]

print(time.process_time() - start)
print(p.memory_percent())
```

Please let me know if there are any efficiencies I am missing with the Python version of the code (or pandas, for that matter), but after several trials, the results were far enough for me to be convinced they are statistically significant:

|  | Process Time (lower is better) | Memory (lower is better) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pandas | ~11s | 4.5% |
| Python | ~14s | 3.1% |

Unless there is some major issue with how I wrote the Python version, it seems to me that Pandas does seem to be more efficient in CPU time, but less efficient in memory.

While the `pandas` library is more memory than the `csv` module, by about a factor of 4, both were significantly less than 50 MB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any overhead (like memory/ cpu) in using pandas in production? Can the 4 lines pandas code written using python's built in modules like csv in 4 or 5 lines?

I'm going to say go with pandas. Once you start slicing and dicing large datasets, numpy arrays are much more efficient than python lists.

Comment: Not memory-wise, necessarily, because you don't have to use lists.